# Undetectable Xiaomi mi4 with Eclipse on mac osx

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, mobile-devices

I bought a Xiaomi Mi4 and I want to use it to develop some android applications. When i run a project on Eclipse, i don't see it in devices. I don't know how to proceed. Someone has an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: First step would be to ensure ADB is installed

Comment: I met similar problems a lot. If you developed in Windows OS. Usually it caused by the cellphone driver. Download the driver from the Cellphone's official website. Install and try again.

Comment: @zz-m adb driver doesn't exist for mac. I found it for Windows but not for mac osx.

Comment: @Fcps Sry， I never developed in mac.

Answer (score 3):

Put the below into your adb_usb.ini file (in linux/osx this is usually in ~/.android/). The MI4 vendor id isn't in the built in ADB database. After that do an adb kill-server && adb start-server (or just reboot if you're lazy).

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x2717
```

Comment: Not working, too. Could you tell me where and how to get this vendor id?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have turned on USB debugging in developer options, if that doesn't help a workaround I have found is instead of using a cable to connect your phone develop over wifi. To do this download one of free playstore applications, just by searching adb wifi. Allow this app root permission through xiaomi security app. After turning the app on you will get a ip address to which you simply connect by ./adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx . Got the job done for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'v updated the SDK and it solved the problem.